# Specifying path to run php file in cron job

Tags: cron, cron-task

I have written a cron job in my Server as below

35 * * * * /home/sites/domain.com/public_html/admin/filename.php

I am trying to call a file in http://domain.com/admin/filename.php.

In Cron job i navigated to every folder by the way its stored in directory in server.But the way to reach the same file in browser is as below

http://domain.com/admin/filename.php

Now the cron filename.php is not running.I checked the file permission every thing is perfect.

I want to know is there a problem in the path i specified

Thanks in advance

Comment: Whats the first line of your php script? and what are the file permissions on it?

Comment: the first line is #!/usr/bin/php which points to php in server

Answer (score 0):

When you run php file in cron. You must config as:

```
35 * * * * /usr/bin/php /home/sites/domain.com/public_html/admin/filename.php
```

and you want run daemon in server. You can setup as:

```
nohup php /home/sites/domain.com/public_html/admin/filename.php &
```